# How to pass a widget to other archive?

Tags: flutter, widget

I have two codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScaffoldModels extends StatelessWidget {

  final Widget bodyWidget;

  ScaffoldModels(this.bodyWidget);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 179, 0, 85),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "ROTA 56 - TESTE",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange, fontSize: 26, fontFamily: ''),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      body: bodyWidget,
    );
  }
}
```

and:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rota56project/defaultmodels/scaffold.dart';

class PlottingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScaffoldModels(_bodyPlotting);
  }
}

Widget _bodyPlotting(BuildContext context) {
  return Container();
}
```

In my main.dart, i called the PlottingScreen..

But in the line :

```
    ScaffoldModels(_bodyPlotting);
```

I receive this message : 
**strong The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable) text**

What is my error?

Comment: return ScaffoldModels(_bodyPlotting);

Comment: but such approach not clever

Comment: what do you think is better to do?

Answer (score 0):

In the line **ScaffoldModels(_bodyPlotting);** , you were using the **_bodyPlotting** as if the **ScaffoldModels** takes a function as its argument

But you want what is returned by **_bodyPlotting** to be passed to the **ScaffoldModels**

What you have to is

```
ScaffoldModels(_bodyPlotting(context));
```